# What is the purpose of running a local DNS proxy server like systemd-resolved?

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved

I was reading about `systemd-resolved` and how it listens on `127.0.0.53` for DNS requests. What is the purpose of running this server and making queries to it when you could directly query a DNS server such as one from Google, Cloudflare, or your ISP instead?

Comment: Try: [Link-Local Multicast Name Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-Local_Multicast_Name_Resolution). It's a pretty sane introduction that states right off the bat, what this is for. [TLDR: if you have a local link and want to resolve local names and private domains locally, this is the way to go...]

Comment: It also caches DNS responses, which should speed up repeated requests.

Comment: If your ISP has a high-performance DNS service available, you may find the best of both worlds by running a local resolver **and** setting it to only **forward** queries (rather than initiating a full recursion of its own) when it has neither an authoritative nor a cached response available.  This allows your system to benefit from the speed of your local cache when possible, and leverages the presumably substantial cache of your ISP when the local cache encounters a miss.

Comment: @JimL. that’s exactly what systemd-resolved does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a local resolver (in general, not just systemd-resolved) can provide a number of benefits; typically, the first one is caching, since most local resolvers will cache responses to queries. This means that repeated queries will be handled faster.

Other benefits can be derived from the fact that the resolver is *local*, and therefore knows about your local environment (which external resolvers can’t). In [systemd-resolved](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html)’s case, that covers:

- a number of [synthetic records](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html#Synthetic%20Records), including `localhost`, `_gateway`, and any entries in `/etc/hosts` (so that applications get consistent resolution, whether they query using DNS directly or `gethostbyname` etc.);
- hosts discoverable using [link-local multicast name resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-Local_Multicast_Name_Resolution) (so that other systems on your LAN can be found through DNS);
- hosts discoverable using [multicast DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS), with a `.local` domain suffix (*e.g.* printers).

It can also enforce policies which only make complete sense locally, *e.g.* DNSSEC.

On top of that, systemd-resolved handles all name resolution services: DNS using its stub resolver, [RFC-3493](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3493)-style [`getaddrinfo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html)/[`gethostbyname`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gethostbyname.3.html), and [its own D-Bus interface](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/org.freedesktop.resolve1.html), again ensuring a consistent experience for all clients, at least at the resolution level (it can’t solve variations arising from the use of proxies for example).